# Print an organized DataFrame from GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame ("test" for this example) where my code loops through different column headings and assigns a certain code to a row based on different calculations:

```
test["test 1"] = eval(f"test['{column}'] {calc}")
test.loc[(test['test 1'] == True), 'Code'] = f"{code}"
```

Then, I perform calculations on any of those rows that have the same code by using groupby:

```
grouped_mean = test.groupby(['Code'])['change'].mean()
grouped_count = test.groupby(['Code'])['change'].count()
```

Then, I am adding the resulting calculation into a DataFrame and must print it during the loop iteration otherwise I get no values:

```
df["Mean"] = grouped_mean
df["Count"] = grouped_count
print(df)
```

Note that each row may have multiple code combinations, therefore I am deleting the column at the end of the loop to prepare for the next loop.

```
del test["Code"]
```

This code works perfectly, but the output is a bit hectic as I am having to print each groupby calculation through the loop, making it difficult to export to a CSV. Empty rows, where a code is not assigned, also prints in a non-friendly way:

```
       Mean   Max   Min  Count
Code                                                    
gaa   0.014  0.02  0.01      5

          Mean   Max   Min  Count
Code                                                          
gab   0.016667  0.02  0.01      6

Columns: [Mean, Max, Min, Count] #If there is no matching code
Index: []
```

My question is, how do I get all of this information to be put into a more readable version, similar to this for the purpose of putting into a CSV I can then distribute:

```
Code   Mean      Max     Min       Count                                                          
gab    0.016667  0.02    0.01      6
gaa    0.016667  0.02    0.01      6
bbc    0.016667  0.02    0.01      6
bac    0.016667  0.02    0.01      6
hag    0.016667  0.02    0.01      6
```

I have tried adding {code} to the df:

```
df["Code"] = code
```

I have tried simply just printing the DF at the end of the full loop, but it prints an empty DataFrame:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Mean, Max, Min, Count, Buy, Buy %, Sell, Sell %]
Index: []
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not see your loop, so here is only idea - first use names aggregation with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) instead multiple aggregations and then in loop append values to list of DataFrame and last, outside loop use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = []

for i in loop:
    #code working per loop
    df = test.groupby(['Code']).agg(Mean=('change','mean'), Count=('change','count'))

    #append DataFrame to list
    dfs.append(df)

big_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! One last question though. For brevity I did not include all the calculations. I omitted Max and Min, which I figured out how to add, as well as an Up vs. Down count. How would I add these via the .agg() function: 
up = test.groupby('Code')['stddev'].apply(lambda x: x[x >= 2].count())
down = test.groupby('Code')['stddev'].apply(lambda x: x[x <= -2].count())

Comment: @jrcart you can use `up = ('stddev', lambda x: (x >= 2) .sum())` and similar for down.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much.